# How to define JSON Schema for Map<String, Integer>?

Tags: json, schema, geojson, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a json :

```
{
"itemTypes": {"food":22,"electrical":2},
"itemCounts":{"NA":211}
}
```

Here the itemTypes and itemCounts will be common but not the values inside them (food, NA, electrical) which will be keep changing but the will be in the format : Map<String, Integer>

How do I define Json Schema for such generic structure ?

I tried :

```
"itemCounts":{
      "type": "object"
    "additionalProperties": {"string", "integer"}

    }
```

Comment: By defining the json shcema, are you asking how to write a class that represents the json?

Comment: @J.West No Schema in the form of JSON

Comment: Is this the [example](http://json-schema.org/example1.html) you want to refer to?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "itemType": {"$ref": "#/definitions/mapInt"},
    "itemCount": {"$ref": "#/definitions/mapInt"}
  },
  "definitions": {
    "mapInt": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": {"type": "integer"}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do we specify which of the two should be treated as "key" here ?

Comment: Keys will always be `string`s in JSON. both `itemType` and `itemCount` in this example are maps of "string" to "integer".
Also note that you don't have to use the `definitions` thing in order to make a map of string to int -- that's just a shortcut used in this example to deduplicate definitions.

Comment: I am searching for how to represent `Map<number, number>`.  I control server and client and thus serializers, but can't figure out how to define the key as a number, any help?

Comment: @ttugates You won't be able to do that in JSON schema since it's that doesn't conform to the JSON specification

Answer (score 6):

The question is kind of badly described, let me see if I can rephrase it and also answer it.

Question: How to Represent a map in json schema like so `Map<String, Something>`

Answer:

It looks like you can use `Additional Properties` to express it https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#additional-properties

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": { "type": "something" }
}
```

For example let's say you want a `Map<string, string>`

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": { "type": "string" }
}
```

Or something more complex like a `Map<string, SomeStruct>`

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": { 
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "name": "stack overflow"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using "additionalProperties" has 2 problems

1. It creates additional class that represents Object or Int Map which internally has additionalProperty as member to be used as Map
2. because its additionalProperties, it always has @JsonIgnore so it wont appear while serialization.

so In my opinion, The right approach would be to use direct Java Type.

```
"properties": {
  "myFieldName": {
    "existingJavaType" : "java.util.Map<String,String>",
    "type" : "object"
  }
}
```

ref: https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score -4):

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "maxItems": 125,
    "items": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": [
            { // key schema goes here },
            { // value schema goes here }
        ],
        "additionalItems": false
    }
}
```

Comment: This defines an array of pairs, not a map