# JSONSchema how to define a schema for a dynamic object

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a JSON response that I am trying to create a JSONSchema for

```
{
    "gauges": {
        "foo": {
            "value": 1234
        },
        "bar": {
            "value": 12.44
        }
    }
}
```

It is important to know that the objects in the associative array `gauges` are dynamically generated so there can be zero to many. Each object in `gauges` will always have a `value` property and it will always be a number.

So each these are valid

#### Example 1

```
{
    "gauges": {
        "foo": {
            "value": 1234
        }
    }
}
```

#### Example 2

```
{
    "gauges": {
        "dave": {
            "value": 0.44
        },
        "tommy": {
            "value": 12
        },
        "steve": {
            "value": 99999
        }
    }
}
```

#### Example 3

```
{
    "gauges": {}
}
```

I have looked though the specification and if this was an array I know I could use `anyOf` but I am unsure how to do this or if it is even possible.

**NB** I cannot change the format of the JSON

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Conceptually what you want is an object representing a Typed Map.

The difficulty is that you have no named property to put your specification in the schema, but in that case You can use **"additionalProperties"**

```
{
"type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "gauges": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
           "value": {"type": "number"}
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

"gauges" property is defined as an object in which every "additionalProperties" will have a type containing a value of type number.

**Note:** In java you would serialize it to a `Map<String,Value>` with Value the classe containing a value. (don't know for other typed language, but I am open to suggestions)

This answer point to an analog solution
[How to define JSON Schema for Map<String, Integer>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40750340/how-to-define-json-schema-for-mapstring-integer)