# validate json object with varying properties

Tags: javascript, json, validation, javascript-objects, jsonschema

I have json object whose property values are unique and can be anything;

```
{
    "cat1": {
        "name": "kitty",
        "type": "animal",
        "color": "ginger"
    },
    "dog2": {
        "name": "ripple",
        "type": "animal",
        "color": "black"
    },
    "book10": {
        "name": "myBook",
        "type": "book",
        "color": "NA"
    },
    "orange6": {
        "name": "NA",
        "type": "fruit",
        "color": "orange"
    },
    "pig1":{
        "name": "spring",
        "type": "animal",
        "color": "pink"
    }
}
```

Now I'm confused how to write its validation schema. Does anybody know how to do it?

```
var mySchema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
         // no idea how to check varying properties like cat1, dog2, etc. which might change next time
    }
}
```

Comment: First you need to ask yourself what will be the rules for validations? Since the values can be anything and properties are varying and you wanna have some validations over them so there should be some predefined set of rules for them. List them out.

Comment: Nice point. I'll take it into account. But what if I only want to validate each object ```{ "name": "name1", "type": "type1", "color": "color1"}``` inside main object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
var mySchema = {
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "name": { "type": "string"},
      "type": { "type": "string"},
      "color": { "type": "string"},
    }
  }
}
```

ref: [JSONSchema how to define a schema for a dynamic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43387839/jsonschema-how-to-define-a-schema-for-a-dynamic-object/43388552)