# How to define map of string to string JSON schema using JSL python library?

Tags: python, dsl, jsonschema

Let’s say among properties of my JSON document one of them holds a collection of HTTP headers which is simply a map of string key to a string value.

```
{
  "property": "value",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "text/css",
    "Last-Modified": "Tue, 08 Aug 2017 18:57:23 GMT",
    "Etag": "123456abc"
  }
}
```

How to define a JSON schema of such document using [JSL](https://jsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) Python library hopefully achieving something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40750892/7598113) on how to define a map of string to an integer.

Also, I would really like to have an explanation of the resulted JSON schema (similarly to what was shown in the mentioned answer) as I am unable to clearly comprehend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSL library provides a **“[DictField](https://jsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/fields.html#jsl.fields.DictField)”** class type for such cases when you wish to define an object (dictionary/map) and describe values type via **“additional_properties”**

For an example:

```
>>> import jsl
... 
... class PayloadSchema(jsl.Document):
...     ip_address = jsl.IPv4Field(required=True)
...     http_headers = jsl.DictField(required=True, additional_properties=jsl.StringField(), min_properties=1)
... 
>>> PayloadSchema.get_schema()
```

This will produce following JSON schema (draft 4):

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "ip_address": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "ipv4"
    },
    "http_headers": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "minProperties": 1
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "ip_address",
    "http_headers"
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```